# Using meteor run --test

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor 0.9.4 and I want to take advantage of the new command line support for running velocity tests. However, when I run meteor run --test then I get a flurry of activity and then the following error messages:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
failed to subscribe to VelocityTestReports subscription
failed to subscribe to VelocityAggregateReports subscription
failed to subscribe to VelocityMirrors subscription
```

I don't know how to debug this. Any suggestions?

I'm doing this on OSX, with the latest version of Meteor, with a set of Mocha tests that worked on the previous release of mike:mocha and velocity.

== Edit ==

This is what I've discovered:

1) To get the tests to appear on the command-line then I need to **meteor add mike:mocha** but this also causes the HTML-Reporter to appear for the live website (the DOT).

2) I was hoping that the HTML-Reporter would not appear when I ran **meteor** without running **meteor run --tests** but the HTML-Reporter still appears.

3) I was hoping that the HTML-Reporter would not appear when I deployed to the live site -- but the HTML-Reporter still appears.

Therefore, I don't think there is anyway to use just the command-line reporting without the HTML-Reporter. I haven't found a way to remove the HTML-Reporter package without removing all of mike:mocha.

Comment: I would suggest posting an issue in the Velocity project: https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity

Comment: do you have the velocity:html-reporter package installed?